# Billing in app issue

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am developing billing-in-app module. But still having some issues.

1) I've implemented License Verification Library(LVL). All done like sample application and tested successfully. But I got error message that : "CHECK_LICENSE permission is not allowed for free application." when upload the app to the market.
I thought that I need to implement LVL because it is related security issue of billing-in-app . But it seems that LVL is only for Paid Application. My application is free and included billing in app module. When it is available for free app ?

2) I've implemented billing-in-app module like the following when payment processed successfully (will call purchasedInApp() method):

```
private class MyAppPurchaseObserver extends PurchaseObserver {

   public MyAppPurchaseObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(MyAppPurchaseObserver.this, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingSupported(boolean supported) {
        //Doing something
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState, String itemId,
            int quantity, long purchaseTime, String developerPayload) {

        if(purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            purchasedInApp();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(RequestPurchase request,
            ResponseCode responseCode) {

        if (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK) {
           //OK
        } else if (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_USER_CANCELED) {
           //Canceled
        } else if(responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE ||
            responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE ||
            responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE ||
            responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR) {
            //Error
        } else {
            //Fail
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreTransactionsResponse(RestoreTransactions request,
            ResponseCode responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK) {
            //OK
        } else {
            //Error
        }
    }
}
```

Above implemented methods are called in main thread ?
Or is it separated thread ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, LVL and in-app billing are independent of one another. The only thing they share is that they use your public key for verification. For in-app billing, your app needs to be built with the `com.android.vending.BILLING` permission.

The billing requests are sent asynchronously to another app on the phone (Android Market or MyApps, depending on the phone). I don't believe that the request issuing methods block, so it's okay to run them on the UI thread or on a background thread. I don't know if the response call-backs are on the UI thread, but I doubt it (since they aren't for LVL).

Comment: Thanks your answer. I've set permission "com.android.vending.BILLING" and received "Order receipt" from android market. But it didn't work "if(purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED)". Could not find the reason. Is there another way to cache payment ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "cache payment". Your app needs to coordinate lots of parts, including both code and the manifest. Have you read through all the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html)?

Comment: oh sorry. I mean "catch". Yeap. I've done all parts with this direction "http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html".

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify exactly what did work and what did not. There are lots of steps to in-app billing, and the PurchaseObserver is kind of at the end of the chain.

Comment: Google Checkout Merchant did work until I receive the receipt. But didn't work callback such as "if(purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED)".

Comment: After you received the receipt, did you launch the pending intent? (This sequence is described in the section "Messaging sequence" in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html).

Comment: Yes. I've implemented 'BillingService' class.

Comment: Did you find the answer, I´m facing the same problem. Tried after reading posts in StackOverflow copying everything in the root (I´m figuring he didn´t set up well his manifest), tried diferent devices, but somehow the entire method onpurchasestatechanged is not called. My card is charged etc. but no response from the market.